# Where does the QR Code Extension store the value "enable qr code token for this event" in Database?

Tags: civievent, extension, api

I installed the "QR Code Checkin" Extension in CiviCRM 5.58.1 with Drupal. When I create a new event, I can activate "enable qr code token for this event".
Now, I want to update my event registration confirmation email text (custom System workflow message template for events): I want to check if the QR Code token is enabled for this event, and if yes, include the QR Code.
So I think I need to access the "enable qr code token for this event" variable via the API (Smarty).

Does anybody know how I can access this variable via API/Smarty? Or where the QR Code Extension stores this variable in the database?
I checked in the table `civicrm_event` but couldn't find this variable. There is no other table having sth like "token" in the name except "payment token".
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Could you specify which extension you are referring to and maybe also your CMS and CiviCRM version? There is for example "QR Code Checkin" (https://civicrm.org/extensions/qr-code-checkin) and "Event Checkin" (https://docs.civicrm.org/eventcheckin/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where it is in the database, but on the Online registration tab of each event after installing the module I now have that selection and the token is available to use in emails.

[image: screen shot showing Enable QR code]

[image: QR code token in Mosaico template]

Comment: One note - we had to make a change to the extension to fix the URL for updating an Attendee status from Registered to Attended. (Next thing after getting the code to show up). https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.qrcodecheckin/issues/28

Comment: Yeah, the token is available in some emails, but it seems that this is not the case in System workflow message templates

Comment: I used Mosaico templates to include the token (with the Mosaico message templates extension) https://civicrm.org/extensions/mosaico-message-templates.